# Oracle XML field - how to know I've parsed everything?

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing

We have an Oracle database, and there is now some XML data stored in an CLOB.  There are nearly 10K records, and we want to know when the data changes, so I've been pulling the data out in a name/value pair record, and saving that to an audit table.  I do that each day, decoding the XML based on definitions stored in a definition file*, saving it to a staging table, then merging in a way that changes are new records.  That allows me to see before and after values.  All that is working fine.

What isn't fine, is there are nearly 10K records, I've spot checked them to make sure I'm getting all the name/value pairs, but I haven't gone through every record.  And even if I've gotten every possibility now, that doesn't mean that there won't be a new name/value in the future.  I've not been given docs on how this data is stored, what the options are or can be.

What is a good way to ensure that I'm picking up all the name/value pairs?  Or to recognize that I'm not getting something?

*I have a table that list the xml field names, and some additional information that allows me to decode it.  It tells me if it is a list, or an array, and helps me to decode it.  It's probably a bit hokey, but I'm not an XML expert.  Obviously.

Here is some example XML (and yes, I realize it is malformed). This is a simple one, I'm dealing with at least dozens of formats, and so far I've identified over 250 name/value pairs, and for this one, I'll list below this example.

```
<calcFinalValuesDetails>
<measured>
    <uom>AMP</uom>
    <shouldRetainMeasuredSq>C1NO</shouldRetainMeasuredSq>
</measured>
</calcFinalValuesDetails>
<processing>
    <formula>ML*R1</formula>
</processing>
<billFactors>
    <billFactorsList>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <billFactor>AMP2MPP</billFactor>
    </billFactorsList>
</billFactors>
```

From this, I am pulling out the following:

```
<uom> = AMP
<shouldRetainMeasuredSq> = C1NO
<formula> = ML*R1
<billFactors>1<billFactor> = AMP2MPP
```

As you can see, it's not important that we fully define each value, but it needs to be enough for the users to recognize, and I want to get ALL values that might be stored.

I've checked, and so far it doesn't appear that the potential XML options are provided.  We write our own reports from the application, but the application itself is not developed in-house.

Comment: Please show example XML and key/value example.  " I've not been given docs on how this data is stored, what the options are or can be." - maybe you need to fix that problem first?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - I've added one simple example.  I suspect the xml formats are proprietary, or at least their release notes don't bother getting into details like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sort of interpreting "name/value" pair as "XML node that has text content, regardless of its depth". This query constructs a intermediate node containing the name and text content for such a node, then extracts those into rows:

```
select x.*
  from xmltable( 'for $n in //*[@text()] return <dummy name="{$n/name(.)}" value="{$n/text()}" />' 
                 passing myxmlvalue 
                 columns "nodename"  varchar2(100) path './@name', 
                         "nodevalue" varchar2(100) path './@value'  ) x
```

where `myxmlvalue` is your XML document. I tested this with your example XML above, after wrapping a `<root>` element around it to make it valid XML and get:

```
nodename                nodevalue
----------------------  ---------
uom                     AMP
shouldRetainMeasuredSq  C1NO
formula                 ML*R1
sequence                1
billFactor              AMP2MPP
```

One possible flaw in this is that I don't think it will pick up empty nodes.

I took inspiration from [here](https://valuetype.wordpress.com/2012/09/15/get-xml-node-name-with-select-statment-in-oracle-db/) in how to get the node name.

Comment: Oooh, I like this idea!  Let me do some work with it - I think I can see a good way forward!  Empty nodes can probably be ignored, providing I have a process that regularly goes through and looks for any new non-empty nodes.